# Git Submodule Won't Delete

Tags: git, github, git-submodules

I'm having an issue adding my submodule back to my project after previously deleting it. When I try to add the submodule everything works perfectly up until I push my changes, git complains:

```
remote: Git submodules detected, installing:
remote: No submodule mapping found in .gitmodules for path 'ng/css/lib/submodule-name'
```

Keep in mind I am installing the submodule to a new location this time around. So in the above snippet, the path in error is from the previous submodule install and not the new one. Where is git retaining this old path information?

---

**Initial Submodule Add**

I added a git submodule

```
git submodule add [github link]
```

while I was in the following directory:

```
ng/css/lib
```

I ended up deleting the submodule as described [here](https://chrisjean.com/git-submodules-adding-using-removing-and-updating/). If you don't want to read that I essentially did this:

```
rm .gitmodules
```

Removed the submodule entry in .git/config

```
git rm --cached ng/css/lib/submodule-name
```

---

Many successful pushes later I wanted to add the submodule back into the project.  I decided it would be as simple as the previous install.

```
git submodule add [github link] ng/global
```

But it wasn't, I get that "No submodule mapping found" error and I don't know how or where git is retaining this info. Is there a way to permanently clean out the submodule install?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your commands did not delete `.git/modules/ng/css/lib/submodule-name`

- Do delete that subfolder first (internal to the `.git` repo folder),
- Make sure your second `git submodule add` did not re-introduce a `.gitmodules` (if yes, remove it first)
- and then try again to add your submodule.

Comment: Yes! The second `git submodule add` was re-introducing a `.gitmodules` file. Deleted, pushed and everything worked perfectly. Thanks!